# Use Ghostscript / PostScript to convert all text colours to black within a PDF

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

I want to convert the white text in this PDF into black text and generate a new PDF with the changed text.

I have found this

http://www.artifex.com/files/Ghostscript_Color_Architecture.pdf

which mentions settings like `-sTextICCProfile` but using `black_output.icc` from

http://www(dot)ghostscript.com/doc/toolbin/color/icc_creator/effects/

like so:

`gs -o test.pdf -sTextICCProfile=black_output.icc out.pdf`

does not change the text colour to black.

Is the usage of the `.icc` profile incorrect? Is it even the right approach?
Is there a way to achieve this with `postscript`?

[Example PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIbrQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the ICCProfile is correct...

However, that usage is for rendering, it has no effect on the pdfwrite device at all (because it doesn't render the input, it turns it into a PDF file). So no, this is not the correct approach.

There is no real means to do what you want with Ghostscript. Technically its probably possible, but it wouldn't be easy. You also haven't apparently posted an example of the PDF file. Its entirely possible that the 'text' is not actually text. It may be an image, or vectors, which **look** like text.

There may also be transparency ivolved which would complicate the matter still further.

Comment: The `Example PDF` link I provided is a snapshot of the relevant part from the PDF in question. I cannot upload the PDF itself due to personal information contained in that PDF. The white text on black background is definitely text. Is there no other way I can influence the output of ghostscript?

Comment: Its possible, its not easy. You would need to modify the code that draws the text so that it changed the colour to black first. If you can understand PostScript then you can modify /ghostpdl/Resource/Init/pdf_draw.ps, look for the routine /ShowText. I believe that if you modify that routine to set the colour space to gray, and the colour to black, then it will emit all colour as black. NB changing the colour to black won't 'redact' the data usefully, it will be easy to cut/paste the text, and trivial for someone who undertands the format to undo.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I do not want to redact any data. I am stripping out images and vector graphics. This will remove the black box around the white text. The next step is to convert the PDF into an image, but this will result in the white text not being shown.

Comment: I found the `pdf_draws.ps` file but it does not contain a routine called `/ShowText`. I am on ghostscript 9.19.

Comment: Looking at the code you should probably modify /showfirst in pdf_ops.ps instead. Put the colour change after setshowstate and before Show.